# Can jinns communicate through dreams?

Tags: children, jinn, dream, sacrifice

Assala-mu'Alaikum, last night I saw a dream where my younger brother was taken away from me and I need to make sacrifices to keep him to me.

At first I heard him screaming then I went out and found him drowning in the pond (We live in a city area, there is no pond here). But just the moment I stepped into the pond, my brother was taken in a boat and was sped off to a specific direction. After swimming to that area I found him hanging on a tight place. I somehow took him down from there and was hugging him. Everything was pitch black. Again that boat came and took me and my brother to a area I have never seen before. Empty ground with torches all around. The jinns there talked with me using my parent's face. And it scared me to death.

Anyways they wanted something my brother had, I couldn't make that out. And that's why a jinn threw him into the water and I rushed to save him but couldn't as a force was stopping me. Once I yelled I am gonna give them 10 children instead of my brother I was able to get to him and save him. Then the same boat took us home.

Note: Our house is kinda jinn proof. Imam did a thing where jinns cannot come aroud our house. Its called 'badhai' in our language.

I have sleep paralysis.

Answer (score 1):

> Narrated Abu Salama: I used to see a dream which would make me sick
> till I heard Abu Qatada saying, "I too, used to see a dream which
> would make me sick till I heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "A good dream
> is from Allah, so if anyone of you saw a dream which he liked, he
> should not tell it to anybody except to the one whom he loves, and if
> he saw a dream which he disliked, then he should seek refuge with
> Allah from its evil and from the evil of Satan, and spit three times
> (on his left) and should not tell it to anybody, for it will not harm
> him. "
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 7044 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7044
>
> Narrated Abu Sa`id Al-Khudri: I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying,
> "If anyone of you saw a dream which he liked, then that was from
> Allah, and he should thank Allah for it and tell it to others; but if
> he saw something else, i.e, a dream which he did not like, then that
> is from Satan and he should seek refuge with Allah from it and should
> not tell it to anybody for it will not harm him."
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 7045 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7045
>
> Abu Hurarirah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
> "Dreams are of three types: The true dream, dreams about something
> that has happened to the man himself, and dreams in which the Shaitan
> frightens someone. So whoever sees what he dislikes, then he should
> get up and perform Salah." And he would say: "I like fetters and I
> dislike the iron collar." And he would say: " Whoever has seen me (in
> a dream) then it is I , for indeed Shaitan is not able to resemble
> me." And he would say: "The dream is not to be narrated except to a
> knowledgeable person or a sincere advisor."
>
> Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2280 https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2280

Shaitan who is a jinn can communicate through dreams. These also have instructions on how to cope with bad dreams.